# How to prevent specific images from being cached by browser with NGINX

Tags: browser, nginx

I have an avatar upload page in my site. But when the user successfully uploaded the avatar the browser keeps showing the old one. How to prevent avatar image from being cached by browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried it myself but this might work:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "^/image/location.png$") {
  add_header Pragma "no-cache";
}
```